# Unix shell descriptor redirection

Tags: linux, shell, unix, file-descriptor, io-redirection

How translate this:

```
echo "test" | tee -a test1 test2
```

To a *pure UNIX* descriptor redirection solution  (oneliner better and no PIPES).

Is it possible?

Comment: In three commands? `echo "test"; echo "test" >> test1; echo "test" >> test2`

Comment: No , i'm just curious about a possible way ohf hanle it by redirections

Comment: In fact `tee` *is* the way to handle this. (btw, I didn't downvote).

Comment: Have a look here : http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/11017-redirect-output-multiple-files.html

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui and Ploutox , so it's not possible at all. I just wanted to confirm it

Comment: It depends on the shell. For example, `zsh` has a `MULTIOS` option which allows `echo test >> test1 >> test2` to append the text to both `test1` and `test2`. (More work would be needed to ensure the output goes to standard output as well, as well as making sure it works whether or not `test1` and `test2` already exist.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a byte written to one file descriptor (pipe, socket etc.) to show up as readable data on more than one file descriptor which are not `dup()`s of each other (but e.g. they correspond to two different regular files), then it's not possible on a generic Unix system. Even if the two file descriptors are `dup()`s, after reading the byte from one of them it would make the byte disappear from the other one, so it can't be read twice.

If you want to do it in Bash without using a `|`, then it's not possible.

If you want to do it in Zsh without using a `|`, then just follow chepner's comment: do `setopt multios`, and then `echo test >>test1 >>test2`. In the background Zsh will create a helper process to do the copying equivalent to what `tee -a` does.